# Is it possible to generate arcgis token that will never expire

Tags: python, arcgis

I'm new to arcgis so please let me know if what I'm trying to do is not the way how things should be done.

I have a server app which periodically does analysis on some data and then is publishing that data back as CSV to arcgis through python arcgis package. This is then displayed on dashboard in arcgis.

My problem is that I cannot find the way to generate token that does not expire. I prefer to store token rather than username/password and I cannot do OAuth2 since this is periodic background task...

Is it possible to generate such token?

I managed to register an app in arcgis and from that I got client_id and client_secret, I could use that to make a call to `arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token` and generate a token which I can use for the duration of session however this token does not allow me to make call to `GIS.item.update` or `GIS.item.publish`...

This is the code I use to generate and use token:

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import json
from urllib3 import PoolManager
from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError

url = "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token"

payload = "client_id=my_client_id&client_secret=my_secret&grant_type=client_credentials"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'accept': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache", }

pool_manager = PoolManager()

try:
    response = pool_manager.request(method="POST", url=url, headers=headers, body=payload, retries=3)
    token = json.loads(response.data)["access_token"]
    print(token) # Token gets generated without any problem
except HTTPError as e:
    print(str(e))

g = GIS(token=token)
i = g.content.get(my_arcgis_item_id)
i.download("/tmp", file_name="my_file_name") # no permission issues here

device_properties = {
    "title": "test",
    "tags": "test",
    "type": "CSV"}

i.update(item_properties=device_properties, data="/tmp/my_file_name") # <-- this fails
```

Last step above fails if I use token generated through REST API. If I just copy/paste token from https://developers.arcgis.com/dashboard then I get no authorization issues (however this token is temporary token...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution may be to get the authorization token generated using oauth2 and then use refresh token to regenerate tokens periodically (https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/token.htm)